# calculating semantic similarity between sets of sentences

Tags: nlp, word2vec, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I have two sets of short messages, I want to compute the similarity between these two sets and identify if they are talking about the same sub-topic based on their semantic similarity. I know how to use pairwise similarity, my problem I want to compute the overall similarity among all the sentences in the two sets not for 2 sentences. Is there a way to use tf-idf or word2vec/doc2vec with cosine similarity to calculate the overall score?

Comment: Sounds like you know the answer! Take the average of word embeddings for all sentences in each set then calculate cosine similarity between the two resulting vectors?

Comment: @ongenz is this possible for tf-idf model?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I did is, take the vectors of each word in each sentence.

Then take the average of the two vectors and do cosine similarity.

Of course before you do that you need a trained word2vec model. doc2vec's similarity is doing the same thing, as internally it keeps a word2vec model.

So you have two options, train a doc2vec, and use its build in similarity, or train a word2vec and do the work by yourself.

Comment: Can I take the average of the pairwise matrix that results from calculating the cosine similarity ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes you can. Just convert every sentence to vectors using Word2Vec and pass the resulting vectors array to Tf-idf model. I am using gensim see this https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html

Answer (score -1):

Infersent helps in finding semantic similarity